# HSM Support in Azure API management

Tags: api, azure, azure-api-management, hsm

We have a client who is interested in using HSM with Azure API management. Is Hardware security module i.e HSM devices supported in Azure API management?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Azure API Management doesn't support hardware based security.  However, we recently added support for getting security information from Azure Key Vault. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/apimanagement/2017/08/23/release-notes-august-23-2017/